# How to make a Simple Leaflet Map work on JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jsfiddle

I've moderate experience with JS and I've been using leaflet for a while. My problem is creating a map by JSFiddle. I've created the file as JSFiddle requires. I'm not getting any errors though I can't see my map. Does anyone one why ?

My code is as follows and as you can see it is working stack's snippet ;

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
 }
 body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
 }
 #map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: where's the link to the fiddle that isn't working?

Comment: It's fixed now. External resources were the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External resources should be loaded using the special "External Resources" tab in JSFiddle, preferably in the same protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) as JSFiddle (due to mixed content). When you did that, you can get it working. Below JSFiddle is working, I created it just now using the default example code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3650w8w3/